# Most general form of motion where period is amplitude independent

Tags: oscillators

Is there another type of motion other than SHM that has this property? How would one systematically find the general form of the motion that respects this constraint?

Comment: What ideas do you have about this?

Comment: never mind ....

Comment: There are a lot of open questions here: do you allow for time dependent forces? Do you allow non conservative forces or forces that depend on the nth time derivative, like e.g. friction?

Comment: @sammygerbil, it was admittedly just a thought - The inspiration was because I recently learnt that a brachistochrone curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve) obeys this property and the motion of a frictionless bead on such a curve is not simple harmonic. 

Assuming you allow a force that depends on the displacement and its time derivatives, is the question still too broad?

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong - Motion on the brachistochrone curve is indeed SHM.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. This is true for *any* linear system whose response happens to be periodic. SHM is just a very special (and simple) case.